# DDD: repository for a nested entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository, aggregate

I have a AR called `User`, which has among other entities one called `City`.

The way I assign a `City` to a `User` is:
`$user->addCity($city);`

The problem comes when a `id` is given at some Controller endpoint instead of a `City` entity, I can't relate them if it's not through an instance and I can't retrieve the entity intance without a repository.

I could retrieve the entity with a `CityRepository` and then add it to the `User` but I though I should only use a repository for ARs.

For the moment, I'm getting the reference through Symfony's EntityManager:

```
    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }


    public function execute(Passenger $user, int $cityId, string $companyName = '')
    {
        $city = $this->users->getCityReferenceById($cityId);
        $user->addCity($city);
        ....
    }
```

while on UserRepository:

```
public function getCityReferenceById(int $cityId): City
{
    return $this->em->getReference(City::class, $cityId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question here is; do you need a ***whole*** city object for the User?

Fair a user is a resident in a city, but in this particular domain, are you concerned with the city details (name, country, etc) from the *perspective of the **user***? or will just having the cityId suffice? - that is to say, would your require functionality to change the name, country, etc. of a city *through a User?*

If the Answer to the former is yes, then I suggest revisiting your Aggregate, perhaps User is not the AR here. If no, and you just want to have the full city details for the purpose of populating a view, then perhaps look into [CQRS](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/), which aims to separate concerns of query/read/display side by introducing a separate read model.

Comment: Thanks, answer is clearly No. I'll take a deeper look into CQRS. So many thinks to learn omg

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are describing (and therefore the use-case you necessitate) is being caused by boundaries being drawn in the wrong places. A `City` is clearly an Entity in it's own right subject to it's own vectors of change. For example, clearly you wouldn't change the `name`, `population`, etc. of a `City` through a `User`.

The *relationship* between a `City` and a `User` seems to be the more interesting idea in your domain, and one that you have not yet made explicit. One can imagine a `Residence` (or maybe a better word) as representing the join between a `User` and a `City` that contains additional information about a given `User`'s relationship with a `City`.

These attributes could be placed on your `[User]` table along with the `[CityId]` or separated into a join table.